# Delphi : Field 'False' not found. occurred only on my computer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a `TCustomClientDataSet` (in memory) which is used to do some filtering in a Delphi program.

My filtering code look like :

```
  CDSFilteredGroup.Filter := 'ACP_type = 1 AND ACP_by_default <> False';
  CDSFilteredGroup.Filtered := True;
```

When I compile and run it, I got the following error only with Delphi (XE4) installed on my computer :

```
CDSFilteredGroup: Champ 'False' non trouvé.
```

Translation: Field 'False' not found. The same code compile and run perfectly fine on my colleagues computers, but not on mine. There must be an option somewhere that I miss, any idea ?

Remember, the code is ok and working...

Comment: That `ACP_by_default` field is a boolean field? I know it's a stupid idea, but what about `(ACP_type = 1) AND (ACP_by_default <> False)` (I hope MIDAS is not such a fool)?

Comment: Thanks, for you answer, but the code is ok, it's work. The problem only occurred when it's compiled on my computer. I am looking for an option somewhere about that.

Comment: I'm not saying it cannot be compiled. It's a string expression that is evaluated at runtime. I was thinking about wrong evaluation.

Comment: Sorry, but your code could not be correct, because you get an error message. The compiler interpretes False an a field. My proposal: (ACP_type = 1) AND (ACP_by_default)

Comment: Yes, but when I compile with another computer, it work at runtime. When I compile with mine it fail at runtime. It's strange...

Comment: You sure it has something to do with compilation? Client dataset uses an external library (MIDAS), as long as you won't include it statically into your project. Run away if you can (and use FireDAC).

Comment: Differences in CDS behaviour on different machines is sometimes caused by different versions of Midas.Dll being on them.  Note; even the same machine may have more than one version of Midas.Dll on it:  the version which is actually used by the CDS is determined by a Registry entry.

Comment: @kobik, Thanks for your answer. Yes, it's a Boolean field, this code is in production without problem for years...

Comment: Ok, I will try to run it with procmon to know which midas.dll it use

Comment: The Midas version used is determined by `CheckDbClient` in DSIntf.Pas.

Comment: @kobik, you are right, done it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *TExprParser* instance used for handling the filter string relies on the resourcestrings given as *STextTrue* and *STextFalse*. You probably have another language than English configured for your IDE library. Try switching to English and see if the error disappears.

To workaround that problem in general replace the text "False" with the content of the resourcestring *STextFalse*.

BTW, this was corrected in later Delphi versions that also accept the literal "False" even in non English environments.

Comment: I have changed the Language Locale ID (in Version Info) to English (US), however it still fail. If i change the value False by STextFalse it work. you must be right, but I can figure out how to change the language in deep enough to test it without changing the code.

Comment: In the Delphi bin folder execute BdsSetLang.exe. This allows to select the IDE language and the library language separately. The library language is the relevant one here.

Comment: You might check your search path for an unexpected copy of Data.DBConsts then.

Comment: Since I wasn't allowed to change the code base, I found another solution : Using Add/Remove Program in control panel, I have modified Delphi XE4 installation and, in the setup, removed any foreign language. Then after recompiling, I didn't have any error. It's not really a solution, but can be a workaround.